# How to debug a django application in a comfortable way?

Tags: python, django, debugging

I'm currently debugging a django application by inserting `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in the code and using the debugger commands to navigate through running application.

The debugger shows the current line, but most of the time it is helpful to have a bit more context. Therefore I open the current file in an editor in another window.

Now whenever the flow changes to another class I need to manually open the new file in the editor. - This feels like there is an easier way to do this.

Is there any kind of IDE integration able to debug a running django application?

Is there some other way I am not yet aware of?

Answer (score 0):

[PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) can do this. Perhaps only the Professional edition which is not free, but has a 30-days trial.

Answer (score 0):

To make your life easier, try IDE like PyCharm.
I use pdb or ipdb to debug simple python file, but they wouldn't be so useful in debugging complex Python scripts.
Also, django-debug-tools is a good tool to debug and optimize Django application.